# Why does my Mac OS X Xcode 4.2 project think I've set an OS X target lower than 10.3

Tags: xcode

I get compile failures because "NSSegmentedControl" (which I use) is reported to be unavailable on OS X prior to 10.3.  Fine.. but I've set my project to 10.7 everywhere. Same issues with Clang and GCC.

Is there a limitation to creating 32-bit OSX applications on Lion?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm building a Standard 32/64bit Universal app and I'm experiencing the same issue so I don't think it has anything to do with your project being 32-bit. What version of Xcode are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's a bug in Xcode.

While the default Deployment document versioning setting for nib files seems to be `Project SDK Version (Mac OS X 10.7)` like shown in the image below, Xcode actually seems to be using `All Versions of Mac OS X`.

[image]

If you change the Deployment target to be a specific version of Mac OS X, rather than the Project SDK Version, (like in the image below), it should prevent the errors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is looking at deployment target in build settings?

Comment: Deployment target is also set to 10.7